# Calculating frequency of values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've dictionary which contains values like this
{a:3,b:9,c:88,d:3}
I want to calculate how many times particular number appears in above dictionary.
For example in above dictionary 3 appears twice in dictionary
Please help to write python script

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {'a':3, 'b':9, 'c':88, 'd': 3}
>>> Counter(d.values()).most_common()
[(3, 2), (88, 1), (9, 1)]
```

Comment: (For large dictionaries, `.itervalues()` might be more efficient in Py 2.x)

Comment: Good point. But since I'm personally using Python 3 and `values` happens to work on both versions, I'll just add the necessary change to the list of quirks Python 2 programmers have to work around anyways ;)

Comment: Yup. :) Was just noting it for future readers, not suggesting that you change your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a defaultdict to do this (basically the more general version of the Counter). This has been in since 2.4.

```
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict( int )

b = {'a':3,'b':9,'c':88,'d':3}
for k,v in b.iteritems():
    counter[v]+=1

print counter[3]
print counter[88]

#will print
>> 2
>> 3
```

Comment: Use `itervalues` ... notice how `k` is not used in your snippet?